# flask global variables errors

Tags: python, flask

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
i = 0
char = arr[0]

@app.route('/<key>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def classNeeds(key):
    global cha,i
    if cha == key:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            i = i+1
            cha = arr[i]
            return 'ok'
        return render_template('index.html') 
    return 'wrong url'
```

I wrote a flask function, it runs okay on localhost, and no logical errors showing on the terminal. However, when I deploy this app on apache2 server, it got logical errors. The error is like, after the `arr[0]` was used, the user can still access this function by using `arr[0]` after a while. But logically the `url/arr[1]` should be the only way to access this route. I am not sure how this error happens. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: `char = arr[i]`?

Comment: Use multiprocessing mode? I'm sorry I didn't use apache2 to deploy my app, but I'm pretty sure if you deployed it by multiprocessing mode, the `arr` will not be shared between different processes.

Comment: that one should be char = arr[i]. My idea is going to assign the URL to users in order, for example, the first person gets arr[0], the 2nd person gets arr[1]... I am not familiar with multiprocessing mode but I will search it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a production server, usually there will be multiple `worker` processes serving your app. The incoming connection can be talking to any one of those processes. If the two connections are not talking to the same processes, they will be dealing with different global variables, thus you wouldn't see a synchronized behavior.

If you want to synchronize state between different connections, you should try use a proper database to store the states.

Comment: Thanks, I also think that was a worker problem. I tried to set the number of worker to be 1 in the mpm_event.conf file but it does not work. Do you mean there should be a database that dealing with all requests and responds? I will search how to implement a database, thank you!

Comment: You are right, it was about workers. After I set all numbers to be 1, it runs well without logical errors.